# Binding to a property of an item from another bound list

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I've got a list of **Validation** objects - validations.

```
public class Validation
{
       public IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Arguments
       { //(...) }
}
```

On a form there is a list bound to validations list and a DataGridView bound to **Arguments** list of current **Validation** from validations list. I allow user to edit selected **Validation** object in a dialog window. The user can modify **Arguments** collection. After closing the window the items displayed in the DataGridView should refresh. They don't. Also if the **Arguments** list is empty after editing, the IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several important interfaces for data-binding; in particular, `IBindingList`, which has the `ListChanged` event that `DataGridView` can listen for.

Is it possible to change the concrete list to a `BindingList<T>`? That should give you most of this for free? You don't need to change the return type, as `BindingList<T> : IList<T>`, and `DataGridView` only knows about the **actual** object (it doesn't care that you call it `IList<T>`).

The other pragmatic option is simply to reset the data-binding on the `DataGridView` - perhaps set the `DataSource` to `null` and then back:

```
object tmp = grid.DataSource;
grid.DataSource = null;
grid.DataSource = tmp; // low-tech data-source reset
```

Comment: IList isn't the issue - that is just an interface; it is the concrete type that matters. If the concrete type is List<T> or ArrayList, then neither implements IBindingList, so neither can proactively tell the DataGridView that changes have happened.